# which methods call before onCreate() of ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

i want to so some changes in the application at run time . whatever the changes i want to do that must be done with in two steps. one step i performed in the `attachBaseContext()` method and another step i have to perform in a method that call before the `onCreate()` method of the `ContentProvider` . so

can any body tell me that which method i can override in my application class which calls before the `onCreate()` method of `ContentProvider` (other then attachBaseContext() ) .

Comment: Well, the `Application` subclass' constructor would be called first, though little of your Android environment will be set up at that point. Why can you not do both steps in `attachBaseContext()`?

Comment: i have already tried this but its not working . so i was thinking to do this in two steps ( one in attachBaseContext() )

Comment: can yoiu tell me which calls first  among constructor or attachBaseContext() ?

Comment: By definition, the constructor has to be invoked first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, of course the constructor will be executed first.

However, if you really need a commit to `android.content.Context`, I recommend using `attachBaseContext`. Although at the moment, i have not found any documentation mentioning `attachBaseContext` in the lifecycle of `android.app.Application`. But my recent tests are that `attachBaseContext` is always executed before `onCreate` happens.

The answer is: `attachBaseContext()`